# How do I make modifications to existing layer(Optional Content Group) in pdf?

Tags: pdf, pdfbox, layer

I am implementing functionality to allow user to draw figures in pdf. I want to draw all the figures in a single layer, which can be made visible or invisible by the user.I am able to create a new layer in a pdf. I am also able to retrieve that layer.But, I am not able to make modification to layer (PDOptionalContentGroup). I tried converting the PDOptionalContentGroup to PDPage and then making desired changes to PDPPage. I also saved the PDDocument.It only created another layer with the same name as previous one, but the changes were not there.Here is the code that I used:

```
PDFont font = PDType1Font.HELVETICA;
PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(src);
PDOptionalContentProperties ocprops = doc.getDocumentCatalog().getOCProperties();
foreach (string groupName in ocprops.getGroupNames())
{
    PDOptionalContentGroup group = ocprops.getGroup(groupName);
    COSBase cosbase = group.getCOSObject();
    PDPage groupPage = new PDPage((COSDictionary)cosbase);
    PDPageContentStream cs = new PDPageContentStream(doc, groupPage, true, false);
    cs.beginText();
    cs.setFont(font, 12);
    cs.moveTextPositionByAmount(150, 200);
    cs.drawString("Testing added to group:" + groupName);
    cs.endText();
    cs.close();
    doc.save(src);
}
```

Comment: I'll try and get back to this later. But as a first hint: it does not make sense to treat an optional content group dictionary as a page, a page references all its content, no matter which ocg it may belong to.

Comment: @mkl Tilman suggested me to use PDcontentstream.beginMarkedContent(). But, I am using 1.8 ver of pdfbox. So, I have to use PDcontentstream.beginMarkedContentSequence(COSName.OC, resourceName);, where resource name is the resource name of optional content group.But, I am not able to fetch resource name corresponding an OCG.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(In a comment the OP indicated that he can only use a 1.8.x version of PDFBox. Thus, the code here is 1.8'ish, tested against PDFBox 1.8.12 for Java.)*

In a comment to your question ["How to get resource names for optional content group in a pdf?"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43345062/1729265) [Tilman Hausherr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/535646/tilman-hausherr) suggested to use the PDFBox class `LayerUtility` as template for own solutions.

Thus, as an example how add to an existing OCG this helper method (based on `LayerUtility.appendFormAsLayer`) shows how to add text to an existing or new OCG. It should be simple to adapt it to adding the content you want to add...

```
void addTextToLayer(PDDocument document, int pageNumber, String layerName, float x, float y, String text) throws IOException
{
    PDDocumentCatalog catalog = document.getDocumentCatalog();
    PDOptionalContentProperties ocprops = catalog.getOCProperties();
    if (ocprops == null)
    {
        ocprops = new PDOptionalContentProperties();
        catalog.setOCProperties(ocprops);
    }
    PDOptionalContentGroup layer = null;
    if (ocprops.hasGroup(layerName))
    {
        layer = ocprops.getGroup(layerName);
    }
    else
    {
        layer = new PDOptionalContentGroup(layerName);
        ocprops.addGroup(layer);
    }

    PDPage page = (PDPage) document.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages().get(pageNumber);

    PDResources resources = page.findResources();
    if (resources == null)
    {
        resources = new PDResources();
        page.setResources(resources);
    }
    PDPropertyList props = resources.getProperties();
    if (props == null)
    {
        props = new PDPropertyList();
        resources.setProperties(props);
    }

    //Find first free resource name with the pattern "MC<index>"
    int index = 0;
    PDOptionalContentGroup ocg;
    COSName resourceName;
    do
    {
        resourceName = COSName.getPDFName("MC" + index);
        ocg = props.getOptionalContentGroup(resourceName);
        index++;
    } while (ocg != null);
    //Put mapping for our new layer/OCG
    props.putMapping(resourceName, layer);

    PDFont font = PDType1Font.HELVETICA;

    PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(document, page, true, true, true);
    contentStream.beginMarkedContentSequence(COSName.OC, resourceName);
    contentStream.beginText();
    contentStream.setFont(font, 12);
    contentStream.moveTextPositionByAmount(x, y);
    contentStream.drawString(text);
    contentStream.endText();
    contentStream.endMarkedContentSequence();

    contentStream.close();
}
```

*([AddContentToOCG](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-pdfbox1/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/pdfbox1/content/AddContentToOCG.java#L66) helper method `addTextToLayer`)*

You can use it like this

```
PDDocument document = new PDDocument();
PDPage page = new PDPage();
document.addPage(page);

addTextToLayer(document, 0, "MyLayer", 30, 600, "Text in new layer 'MyLayer'");
addTextToLayer(document, 0, "MyOtherLayer", 230, 550, "Text in new layer 'MyOtherLayer'");
addTextToLayer(document, 0, "MyLayer", 30, 500, "Text in existing layer 'MyLayer'");
addTextToLayer(document, 0, "MyOtherLayer", 230, 450, "Text in existing layer 'MyOtherLayer'");

document.save(new File(RESULT_FOLDER, "TextInOCGs.pdf"));
document.close();
```

*([AddContentToOCG](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-pdfbox1/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/pdfbox1/content/AddContentToOCG.java#L48) test method `testAddContentToNewOrExistingOCG`)*

to add text to existing or not yet existing OCGs.

Comment: Thanks it works.Only thing one extra thing that I used is checking if a resource name already exists for the OCG, then I use that for modifying OCG.